# Controlling when SQL UPDATE is executing on ehcache 'd classes

Tags: hibernate, caching, ehcache

We are using Hibernate and ehcache as 2nd level cache.

If I load an entity that is cached (e.g. cache-usage="read-write") and update it, it seems that this immediately results in an SQL UPDATE.

(How) Can I influence when this SQL UPDATE happens?

> ```
>         hibSession = HibernateUtil.getReadWriteSession();
>         tx = hibSession.beginTransaction();
>         User u = (User) hibSession.load(User.class, user_id);
>         u.modify();
>         hibSession.update(u);
>         tx.commit();
> ```

Edit: It seems that setting a [CacheMode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/CacheMode.html) should have an effect, but each hibSession.update() results in an immediate SQL UPDATE, regardless which CacheMode I set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I load an entity that is cached (e.g. cache-usage="read-write") and update it, it seems that this immediately results in an SQL UPDATE.

This seems to be a **very good** thing to me.

> It seems that setting a CacheMode should have an effect, but each hibSession.update() results in an immediate SQL UPDATE, regardless which CacheMode I set.

SQL UPDATEs are performed when the session is **flushed** (when the tx is committed here) and this is just the expected behavior. I don't see anything in the `CacheMode` that could change this and I really don't understand why you would like to change this behavior. I mean, when do you want the UPDATEs to be performed? Outside the transaction? I must be missing something. Can you clarify?

---

**Update:** It appears the question was about Write-Behind caching. So, quoting [Terracotta's Hibernate Integration](http://tusharkhairnar.blogspot.com/2009/06/terracottas-hibernate-integration.html) to clarify:

> #### Write-Behind Caching
>
> When you think of cache you will arrive at
>   these cache strategies : Read-Through
>   Caching, Write-Through Caching,
>   Write-Behind Caching. **Hibernate Second
>   Level cache is Read-Write-Through
>   Cache** where if cache miss occurs,
>   entity is read from database and then
>   handed over to cache for susequent
>   access. **But H2LC is not Write-Behind
>   caching**. With Terracotta's disk
>   persistence and asynchronsous module
>   it would be really efficient for
>   certain use-cases to implement
>   write-behind. **Currently Hibernate just
>   directly writes to database**. Instead
>   if its modified to write to second
>   level cache and persistent
>   async-database-queue, this would
>   decrease latency and increase
>   throughput dramatically.

Write-Behind is just not how Hibernate currently works.

Comment: i guess what i am thinking about is Write-Behand-caching, mentioned here: http://ehcache.org/documentation/write_through_caching.html

i'm not sure if that introduces other problems, of course, and i don't know whether that would be compatible with Hibernate (though i dont see any big reasons why it should not).

Comment: @thomers I see. But I don't know if this can work with Hibernate. What if the changes can't be made in the database because of optimistic locking for example? I must think about this deeper (I can see that Coherence, Infinispan, Ehcache does offer write Behind caching but I really wonder if this is supported by Hibernate).